# Need to extract attachments from Outlook (.msg) attachment via Lotus Notes

Tags: outlook, lotus-notes, attachment, lotusscript

I have written an agent that extracts all attachments from all documents in a database and saves them to a local hard drive. However, many of those attachments are Outlook messages (.msg files) that also contain attachments (i.e., attachments within attachments). I need to extract those secondary attachments. My agent is written in LotusScript, but I am open to doing this in Java as well. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the attachment using `Attachment.SaveAsFile`, then open the MSG file using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`.

Comment: Dmitry - Thanks for your idea. This appears to be a tool used in VBA and C++. Are you aware of a java equivalent I can use inside Lotus Notes without having to import a third-party API? I have to do these extractions from within Lotus Notes and I cannot add third-party tools because of admin security restrictions. Thx

Comment: I thought LotusScript could use COM objects? In Java, you can use JACOB.

Comment: Of course you are correct, Dmitry. My brain, having spent a lot of time with XPage coding these days, momentarily forgot some LS basics. Thank you for your help.